# gcd in spreadtab error

Tags: tables, calc, spreadtab, gcd

why wont my code work? I get up to 22 errow massages

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fp}

\begin{document}
\STautoround{3}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{|c|D{.}{,}{3}|c|c|}}
    \SThidecol&\SThidecol&\SThidecol&@$(hkl)$
    &@\mathclap{\hspace*{10pt}d_{hkl}\,[\si{\angstrom}]}
    &@$2\theta$&@$(h,k,l)$\\
    0&0&1&@(001)&
    \STcopy{v}{1/((a2/3.83)^2+(b2/3.89)^2+(c2/11.7)^2)^(1/2)}&
    \STcopy{v}{arcsin(1.5406/(2*e2))}&
    \STcopy{v}{gcd(a2,b2,c2)}\\
    0&0&4&@(004)&&&\\
    0&0&5&@(005)&&&\\
    0&1&2&@(012)&&&\\
    0&1&3&@(013)&&&\\
    1&0&2&@(102)&&&\\
    1&0&3&@(103)&&&\\
    1&1&0&@(110)&&&\\
    1&1&1&@(111)&&&\\
    1&1&2&@(112)&&&\\
    1&1&3&@(113)&&&\\
    2&2&2&@(222)&&&\\
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think that the numbers should be nonzero for `gcd`. I tried the example in the manual and changed one of the numbers to zero, getting the error.

Comment: is there a possibility to let the result be 1 for zero numbers?

Answer (score 2):

The manual doesn't mention it, but if I try

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{rrr}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{@Numbers} & @GCD \\
\midrule
0 & 1 & \STcopy{v}{gcd(a2,b2)} \\
\bottomrule
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

I get

```
New spreadtab: \begin{tabular}{rrr}
* reading tab: ok
* computing formulas:
     cell A2
     cell B2
! Extra \or.
\STeval@cell@i ...distant@rownumber )}\fi \fi \or
                                                  \let \ST@tobereplaced \ST@...
l.13 \end{spreadtab}
```

You can check whether a number equals zero. For instance, this yields the correct result for the above table.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{rrr}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{@Numbers} & @GCD \\
\midrule
0 & 12 & \STcopy{v}{gcd(ifeq(a2,0,b2,a2),ifeq(b2,0,a2,b2))} \\
\bottomrule
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

Except, of course, if both numbers are zero.

[image]

Comment: Ok my wantet result ist
\STcopy{v}{gcd(
        ifeq(ifeq(a2,0,b2,a2),0,c2,ifeq(a2,0,b2,a2)),
        ifeq(ifeq(b2,0,c2,b2),0,a2,ifeq(b2,0,c2,b2)),
        ifeq(ifeq(c2,0,a2,c2),0,b2,ifeq(c2,0,a2,c2)))}